# persistant html input placeholders

Tags: javascript, css

A bit of an odd one... what I'd like is for my input placeholder text to do something like:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align:right;
    opacity:.3;
}
```

when the user enters text instead of disappearing entirely. Is this at all possible without a huge javascript hack?

Thanks

Comment: Use a background image that is a picture of two lines of placeholder text: non transparent, and semi-transparent. Then use `background-position` style to move the background so that the semi-transparent text is in view. e.g.: `input { background-image: url("placeholders.jpg"); }` and `input:focus { background-position: 20px; }`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not going to do that to a lot of input boxes, Using background image (with your placeholder text) would help

```
 input {
    background:white url(bgtextimage.png) no-repeat; /* image with your placeholder text*/
    }
    input:focus {
    background:white url(bgtextimage_3.png) no-repeat; /* placeholder text image with an opacity if 0.3 */
background-position: right 0px; /* if you want to align text to right */
    }
```

Now you need to stop the background image from moving left when the element is out of focus. I'm using jQuery for this purpose

```
$('.myinputfield').blur(function()
{
    if( $(this).val().length === 0 ) {
        $(this).css('background','left 0px'); //keep it to left if the element is empty
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('background-position','right 0px'); //move to right if there's some text
    }
});​
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/QuHen/1/

Comment: Now that's an idea. I hadn't considered that. Thanks!

Comment: Ah. There's a problem. When the input is blurred the image moves back left, overlapping anything put into the field. And as there's no way of testing the value of a input with css as far as I know (oh, if only input[value=""] actually worked like it should...) that idea is pretty well shot.

Comment: You can use Javascript IF condition to check if there is any text in the box. If true, keep the image on right.
Wait i'll write a code for you

Comment: Yeah, if I'm going to use a javascript solution, there are more flexible ways of doing it. See my fiddle below.

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks like there is no way to get this behavior purely through CSS.

I've come up with a quick jQuery plugin that will do it for me. Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/puTM3/

A quick:

```
$("input[placeholder]").placeholder();
```

once the dom is loaded should take care of 90% of your use cases.

What sucks is if you edit the dom dynamically, any new/modified inputs need to be re`.placeholder()`ed.

Anyone have any better ideas?